# Add a number to all the elements in a matrix except the diagonal elements

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, numpy-ndarray, diagonal

I wanted to add a constant number to all the elements in a matrix but except to the diagonal elements.

```
e.g., matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                         [4, 5, 6],
                         [7, 8, 9]])
```

```
Desired output : adding 10 to all the elements except to diagonal elements
       matrix = np.array([[1, 12, 13],
                         [14, 5, 16],
                         [17, 18, 9]])
```

How can I exclude diagonal elements from this operation ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an identity matrix multplied by the number you add and subtract like this:

```
import numpy as np

x= 9 #number to add

matrix = np.array([ [1, 2, 3],
                    [4, 5, 6],
                    [7, 8, 9]])

matrix2 = matrix + x - (np.identity(len(matrix))*x) 

print(matrix2)
```